# How can i make a flex item fill its parents empty space when the parent gets resized?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

As seen in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/SuperHerp/pen/JjOOrjv), when the page is loaded, the orange box (area that gets filled with text over time) does not fill enough space to push the pink box (textarea to push text into orange box) to the bottom of the green box (div element to hold textwindow and textarea). however when i zoom in on the page itself it suddenly does.
how do i achieve this behaviour without zooming in?

Im a beginner and i would like to not switch display options to float/block/grid/whatever.
Beyond that i dont care how it is achieves (CSS/js).

Some relevant code at a glance:

```css
.Menu{
     margin-left: 10%;
     margin-right: 10%;
     border: black solid 5px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     min-height: 300px;
     max-height: 90vh;
  }
  .MsgComposer{
     border: green solid 5px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     flex-grow: 1;
     max-height: 90vh;
  }
  .MsgWindow{
     border: orangered inset 2px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     min-height: 75vh;
     max-height: 90vh;
  }
  .InputField{
     border: violet solid 5px;
     display: inherit;
     flex-flow: row;
     flex-wrap:nowrap;
     width:auto;
     align-items: flex-end;
     min-height: 1pt;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="Menu">
      <div class="MsgAndInput">
    <div class="persistentBtn">
      <button id="MenuBTN" title="Menu" value="noHide" onclick="toggleVis('persistentBtn')"></button>
      <button id="showSrv" title="Show/Hide Servers" onclick="toggleVis('serverSelect')"></button>
      <button id="showUsr" title="Show/Hide Users  " onclick="toggleVis('userSelect')"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="Select">
      <div class="serverSelect" id="ServerList">
        <b style="color: white;">Server:</b>
        <ul id="UserServerSelection">
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
          <li value="Server-1">serverPlaceholder</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="userSelect" id="UserList">
        <b style="color: white;">Person:</b>
        <ul name="UserRecipientSelection" id="UserRecipientSelection">
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
          <li value="name">namePlaceholder</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="MsgComposer">
      <div class="MsgWindow" id="Messages">
        <!--Window with messages received/sent-->
      </div>
      <div class="InputField">
        <textarea id="UserMessage" placeholder="Enter Text here..."></textarea>
        <button id="SelectAttachment" title="Attach something..." onclick="uploadFileName()">
          <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="FileUpload">
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the HTML, not just the CSS. The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added the html code

Comment: And I've copied it into a Stack Snippet for you (please, again, see the links above).

Comment: The tl;dr does not match the actual question. If you want a fixed percentage, you don't need flexbox at all, you can just use divs stacked on top of each other.

Comment: @Thomas im very new to css and layouts, so i didnt know with flex i dont need percentages. my monkey brain thought: 2 elements, one needs to be 80% of the parent the other 20% -> done! Thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put `flex-grow: 1;` on `.MsgWindow`. This makes it grow vertically (because it's inside a `flex-direction: column;` element) to take up all remaining space.

Comment: This worked, and i dont know how i didnt find that out myself... thank you very much